# Quotienting by the Leading Term Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

> Somewhat related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435905/quotient-of-a-polynomial-ring-and-leading-terms) question, I'm looking for sources that give a proof of
>   $$S / I \cong S/\mathrm{LT}(I),$$
>   where $I \lhd S = k[x_1, ..., x_n]$ for $k$ a field, and the isomorphism is **an isomorphism as vector spaces**.

This seems to be true because $S$ is Noetherian and hence $I$ is finitely generated, meaning that for $I = \langle f_1, ..., f_r \rangle$ where WLOG $\{f_i\}$ are monic, then any monomial which is divisible by some $\mathrm{LT}(f_i)$ is replaced by a sum of lower degree monomials (here we can take $\{f_i\}$ to be a Groebner basis), so for the sake of counting basis elements in a vector space isomorphism, quotienting out by the leading term achieves the same effect.

More generally, I'm looking for sources and/or proofs about this statement when $k$ is not a field (in particular, when $k = \mathbb{Z}$), so that there'd be a $k$-module isomorphism, though I'm unsure if this even holds due to modified description of Groebner bases over PIDs.

Comment: The set of monomials $m\in S$ that don't belong to $\mathrm{LT}(I)$ is a $k$-basis for $S/I$; see [Theorem 2.14](http://www.math.utah.edu/agtrtg/commutative-algebra/Boocher_lectures.pdf).

Comment: This is false for $k = \mathbb{Z}$ (assuming that by "vector spaces" you mean "$k$-modules" in this generality). For example, if $n = 1$, $x_1 = x$, and $I$ is the ideal generated by $2x - 1$, then $S/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\left[1/2\right]$ and thus torsionfree as an abelian group, whereas $S/\operatorname{LT}(I) = S / \left(2x\right)$ (since $\operatorname{LT}(I) = \left(2x\right)$) is not torsionfree as an abelian group.

Comment: However, such an isomorphism does exist when $I$ has a Gröbner basis (even if $k$ is not a field). This follows from Proposition 3.10 in my [*t-unique reductions for Mészáros’s subdivision algebra*, detailed version](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/subdiv-v7-long.pdf) (a well-known fact), because this proposition constructs a basis for $S / I$ formed by projections of the $G$-reduced monomials, but clearly there is also a basis of $S / \operatorname{LT}\left(I\right)$ formed by projections of the same $G$-reduced monomials. When $k$ is a field, $I$ always has a Gröbner basis.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Many thanks for the counterexample and link. I'm confused as to why $2x - 1$ is not a groebner basis then, as $LT(I) = <LT(2x - 1)> = (2x)$ from what I can tell. Does a groebner basis not exist in this case and if so when does a groebner basis exist for ideals of polynomial rings over $R$ Noetherian?  Adams and Loustaunau's introduction to groebner bases seems to say that such a basis exists for all $I \lhd R[x_1, ..., x_n]$ with $R$ Noetherian (Corollary 4.1.17 on p. 209 for reference).

Comment: In my link, I require a Gröbner basis to consist of monic polynomials. I think some standard texts loosen this condition by only requiring the leading coefficients to be invertible, but this boils down to the same thing, except that you have to carry some scalars around. Now, $2$ is not invertible in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I do see that in your paper. If the polynomials are allowed to be not monic, do you know when this isomorphism holds?