# Is there an algorithm to determine irreducibility of multivariate polynomials?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose I have a polynomial $f\in k[x_1, \cdots , x_n]$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. Is there a way to determine whether $f$ is irreducible over $k$?

So far I have found [Irreducible homogeneous polynomials of arbitrary degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24425/irreducible-homogeneous-polynomials-of-arbitrary-degree?rq=1) and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105304/criteria-for-irreducibility-of-polynomial/105323#105323 but neither are close to the general case I am looking for. Is the question I am asking a still open one?

Comment: To avpid closing, show some of your effort at solving.

Comment: @Piita Thanks for your comment. If my previous effort was mostly searching rather than solving by myself, then would it be more appropriate for me to add what I had found to the content of the question or to the comment?

Comment: Since you're asking for an algorithm, it might be useful to specify how $f$ is encoded.

Comment: @user3425253 Typically you'd either state where your interest is coming from, why it is that you can't even start tackling the problem, or what insights you (believe to) have, s.t. people can point you in the right direction, or highlight where you have a wrong/incomplete understanding/intuition. Showing concrete first steps at solving does all of this together and is thus welcomed as a sign of gratitude towards those who take their time helping you.